# Why can't Coq define a mutually inductive append of parametrized even/odd lists?

Tags: coq

I am following Chlipala's book with Coq and I tried to extend his mutually inductive definition of appending even/odd lists but I get a recursion error by Coq:

```
Module mutual_induct.

  Inductive even_list (T: Set) : Set :=
  | ENil
  | ECons (t: T) (ol: odd_list T)
  with odd_list (T: Set) : Set :=
  | OCons (t: T) (el: even_list T).

  Compute ENil.

  Fixpoint elength {T: Set} (el: even_list T) : nat :=
    match el with
    | ENil _ => 0
    | ECons _ _ ol => 1 + olength ol
    end
      
  with olength {T: Set} (ol: odd_list T) : nat :=
    match ol with
    | OCons _ _ el => 1 + elength el
    end
  .

  Fixpoint eapp {T: Set} (el1 el2: even_list T) : even_list T :=
    match el1 with
    | ENil _ => el2
    | ECons _ t' ol' => ECons T t' (oapp ol' el2)
    end
  with oapp {T: Set} (ol: odd_list T) (el: even_list T) : odd_list T :=
    match ol with
    | OCons _ t' el' => OCons T t' (eapp el el')
    end
  .     
           
End Mutual_induct.
```

got error:

```
Error: Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix.
```

Obviously I am just learning Coq and I suppose that is why he didn't try to do it that way to not distract the reader from a weird bug... but I want to have it parametrized. How do I fix this and why is Coq complaining? (I understand intuitively it can't guess something is decreasing but from my perspective nothing seems obviously wron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive definition in Coq is well formed only when the recursive calls are performed on subterms of the principal argument of the function. The problem with `oapp` is that the recursive call is performed on the *other* argument `el` (`oapp el el'`), which was probably a typo. Here is a corrected version:

```coq
Module mutual_induct.

  Inductive even_list (T: Set) : Set :=
  | ENil
  | ECons (t: T) (ol: odd_list T)
  with odd_list (T: Set) : Set :=
  | OCons (t: T) (el: even_list T).

  Compute ENil.

  Fixpoint elength {T: Set} (el: even_list T) : nat :=
    match el with
    | ENil _ => 0
    | ECons _ _ ol => 1 + olength ol
    end

  with olength {T: Set} (ol: odd_list T) : nat :=
    match ol with
    | OCons _ _ el => 1 + elength el
    end
  .

  Fixpoint eapp {T: Set} (el1 el2: even_list T) : even_list T :=
    match el1 with
    | ENil _ => el2
    | ECons _ t' ol' => ECons T t' (oapp ol' el2)
    end
  with oapp {T: Set} (ol: odd_list T) (el: even_list T) : odd_list T :=
    match ol with
    | OCons _ t' el' => OCons T t' (eapp el' el)
    end
  .

End mutual_induct.
```